# postgresql connect to postgres database from given ip

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I know this might be really a simple question but I don't know what to do.
i want to connect to database on server2 from this 10.15.13.12.
how should i add my source to do the connection please, i mean from 10.15.13.12 to server2?

**I did**

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:pwd@server2/mydb')
```

Thank you,

Comment: This has nothing to do with connection string. You need to configure the postgres instance to allow connections from the given address.

Comment: how to do it please?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: @jira thank you ! i can ping the database machine from the server ! is it what do you mean?